# How to share one internet connection from LAN to another LAN?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

[image: want my mac to access Internet]

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a router (Router1) with internet connection in `en0`, with IP `192.168.1.110`,
however I have my RPi's wifi port (`wlan0`) connected to another router (Router2) with IP `172.31.198.123` (another LAN network).

Now my Macbook is connected to Router2(e.g. with IP `172.31.198.100`), and I want to reach the internet through my Raspberry Pi (maybe setting up a VPN server or something like that on the Pi).

Only when I take out my cable (`en0`), can I ping through `172.31.198.123` from my Mac.
Otherwise the Pi will use `en0` and I can't ping through  `172.31.198.123`.

Could anyone tell me how to do it?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

~$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="XXXX-WiFi"
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Comment: it would help if you drew a picture.

Comment: @hildred I added a picture!!

Answer (score 0):

Any machine with multiple network interfaces must have multiple routes specifically you need to have three on three rpi and two on the mac, that is one fore each subnet and a default route. (assuming that you are just using the second router as a bridge, which looks to be the case)

Now here is the interesting question, why is the routes not configured automatically? I suspect that the first issue is that router2 is running a dhcp server and that the rpi is using that dhcp server (which although technically not a problem makes a royal mess of things unless you know exactly what you are doing) and that your network configuration tool that you are using the rpi is a best client type (only use the best network) and you are trying to use it as a double client (connected to two or more networks at the same time, do not forward packets between interfaces) or as a router (connected to two or more networks at the same time, forward packets between interfaces). If you are trying to connect the mac to the internet through the rpi, you will need to specify the rpi as the default gateway to the mac, and enable packet forwarding.

Comment: Maybe I can set up a VPN server or some proxies on Pi and let my mac connect to that? Please give me some command line instructions since I'm not familiar with network configuration.@hildred

Comment: a vpn aside from being completely unnecessary  won't work until you get the underlying network working. What network configuration tool are you using on the rpi?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to find out that. I use Raspbian's default configuration tool..I post my interface content here. By the way the Router2 is actually a big LAN of my campus, Router1 is my dorm router.

Comment: so router 2 has internet access?

Comment: Nop. I don't want to log in its network renting system to gain Internet access. It's another different ISP from my dorm's. I just want to share my dorm's Internet access utilising Campus's WIFI network.

Comment: ok, what you want to do can be done, but there are two challenges, the first is we need to disable the network autoconfiguration on the rpi, and second, we need to override the default route on the mac while still getting the ip address from dhcp. I will do some checking, but fire up the package manager on the rpi and see if you can figure out which network managers you have installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24558/discussion-between-hrlty-and-hildred).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach is masquerading (more commonly known as dynamic NAT) using iptables.

In your rasperry pi, do the following:

1. load the iptables NAT module: `modprobe iptable_nat` (this step may fail if the module is already up, so try to continue either way)
2. Enable ip forwarding: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
3. Set up a masquerading rule in your iptables:

   ```
   iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o wlan0 -s 172.31.198.0/24 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
4. Add the following rules to make sure iptables will not drop this packets in an earlier stage of the filtering:

   ```
   iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o wlan0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

   iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i wlan0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   ```

Now you will need to make it so that traffic heading to the internet will get to the raspberry pi for its further routing. You have 2 options for doing so:

1. In your router (router2), define the ip address of the raspberry pi (on the wifi card) as the default GW.
2. Change the default GW of the mac to the raspberry pi IP. You can do this with the following commands:

   ```
   route del default
   route add default 1.2.3.4
   ```

   When 1.2.3.4 is the IP address on your raspberri pi wifi NIC.

   You may want to keep it as a script so you can run it every time you connect to that network.

Naturally, if possible, option 1 is better. It will route all devices connected to it to the internet (but as you said in the comments, that may not be what you want) and it does not have the disadvanted of having to define a static route in your mac (you may also need to remove it when connecting to other networks).

Doing this should tell your rasppi device to forward all packets coming from router2 to the internet, changing their src ip address in the header to the one of the external NIC in the raspberry pi. When a response will arrive for these connections, the raspberry pi will know where to route them back to. This is in short the process of masquerading.

You can look at more details about this in here:
[http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch14*:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables#Masquerading_.28Many_to_One_NAT.29](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables#Masquerading_.28Many_to_One_NAT.29)

Comment: Router2 is actually a big LAN of my campus, Router1 is my dorm router. I don't want to log in the network renting system of my campus LAN to gain Internet access. I want to share my dorm's Internet access utilising Campus's WIFI network. So I can't modify any config in router 2, would that matter?

Comment: Well, naturaly it would, because while the raspi will forward any traffic coming to it to the internet, router2 will not forward such traffic to the raspi. **However**, there is another way you can get your mac to send such traffic to the raspi. That is, to define the default GW of the mac as the raspi. I will edit my answer to include that option shortly.